# Rotate an object according to a plane normal

Tags: c#, matrix, xna

I am making a FPS game, I created a peaceful AI for the moment and when the character is died, I just want it to be oriented according to the normal below it. I show you the result for the moment :
[image]

as you can see, the character is flying, because the terrain is not straight.

I am trying (without success) to make something like that : 
[image]

I have the (x,y,z) coordinates (character position) and the normal to the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Your character's death pose is always with the normal facing up, right?
And you want to rotate it to another normal.

You can find a Quaternion that represents the rotation between two vectors (up and the new normal) to rotate the mesh.
This question has the answer to that:
[Quaternion from two vector pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445934/quaternion-from-two-vector-pairs/20038551#20038551)

To know the normal of your terrain, you can probably cast a ray down and get the normal from the collision information depending on the physics engine you are using.

Edit:
Some background info:
A quaternion represents a rotation. So what I'm suggesting is that you use the answer from the question I linked to calculate the rotation between the default orientation of the character's death pose (UP) to the new orientation (Terrain Normal)

Then you can just transform your dead character with the Quaternion and it'll follow the terrain's normal.

Here's a sketch: calculate Q from UP and N with the solution from the Link and rotate your character's model with Q:

[image: sketch]

Answer (score 0):

Yes the normal is always facing up, as you can see on my drawing, even if I drew it in the good pose. I dont understand when you are talking about the quaternion, which new normal are you talking about ? 
I already have the normal of the plane under the character, so, part of the jobs is already done :)